# Sugar get_entry_list returns "Invalid Session ID" when querying Meetings for a specific user

Tags: java, android, soap, sugarcrm

I try to query Sugar through its REST API using Java for entries in Meetings module for a specific user, namely the one who is logged in currently.

I am trying this a few days already while googling around for asolution.

I made a login() call, where I got a session ID, than I make a call to get_user_id(). With the returned user ID I try to query the Meetings module by using get_entry_list().

To get the Meetings assigned to the UserID it works with following query string, where mUserId holds the returned user id of get_user_id():

```
queryString = "meetings.assigned_user_id='"+mUserId+"'";
```

But I not only want to get the meetings, where a user is assigned to, but all Meetings where he participates. For that I try a subquery on meetings_users table in my query.

Here is a query strings I tried, which os working on MySQL prompt. But when I try this over REST, it returns "Invalid Session ID":

```
queryString = "meetings.id IN ( SELECT meetings_users.meeting_id FROM meetings_users WHERE meetings_users.user_id = '"+mUserId+"' )";
```

Does anyone have a hint on this? Which conditions lead to an "Invalid Session ID" at all?

What also does not work e.g. is appending "and deleted = '0'" to the first stated query:

```
queryString = "meetings.assigned_user_id='"+mUserId+"' and deleted = '0'";
```

also fails.

As requested here is the full code example, platform is Android, API Level 8:

```
private JSONArray getEntryList(String moduleName,
        String selectFields[], String queryString, String orderBy, int max_results) throws JSONException, IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    JSONArray jsoSub = new JSONArray();
    if (selectFields.length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectFields.length; i++)
        {
            jsoSub.put(selectFields[i]);
        }
    }

            // get_entry_list expects parameters to be ordered, JSONObject does
            // not provide this, so I built my JSON String on my own
    String sessionIDPrefix = "{\"session\":\""+ mSessionId+ "\"," +
            "\"modulename\":\""+ moduleName+ "\"," +
            "\"query\":\""+ queryString + "\"," +
            "\"order_by\":\""+ orderBy + "\"," +
            "\"offset\":\""+ mNextOffset+ "\"," +
            "\"select_fields\":["+ jsoSub.toString().substring(
                    1, jsoSub.toString().length()-2)+ "\"],"+
            "\"max_results\":\""+ 20 + "\"}";

    String restData = sessionIDPrefix;
    Log.d(TAG, restData);

    String data = null;
    String baseurl = mUrl + REST_URI_APPEND;

    data = httpPost(baseurl+"?method=get_entry_list&input_type=json&response_type=json&rest_data="+restData);

    Log.d(TAG, data);   
    JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject(data);

    mResultCount = jsondata.getInt("result_count");
    mNextOffset = jsondata.getInt("next_offset");

    return jsondata.getJSONArray("entry_list");
}

private String httpPost(String urlStr) throws IOException{
    String urlSplitted [] = urlStr.split("/", 4);
    String hostPort[] = urlSplitted[2].split(":");
    String hostname = hostPort[0];
    int port = 80;
    if (hostPort.length > 1)
        port = new Integer(hostPort[1]);

    String file = "/"+urlSplitted[3];

    Log.d(TAG, hostname + ", " + port + ", " +file);

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http", hostname, port, file);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_malformed_url).toString());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "URL "+url.toString());
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_conn_creat).toString());  
    }
    conn.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
    try {
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_post).toString());
    }
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_conn_open).toString()
                 + "\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

    int response = 0;
    String responseMessage = null;
    try {
        response = conn.getResponseCode();
        responseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        conn.disconnect();
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_resp_io).toString());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception Response "+ response);
    if (response != 200) {
        conn.disconnect();
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_http).toString()
                 + "\n" + response + " " + responseMessage);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"line " + line);
            sb.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        conn.disconnect();
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_resp_read).toString());
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    if (sb.toString() == null)
    {
        throw new IOException(mContext.getText(R.string.error_resp_empty).toString());
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Calling the code above:

```
        if (login() != OK)
    return null;

    mResultCount = -1;
    mNextOffset = 0;

    mUserId = getUserId();

    String fields[] = new String [] {
        "id",
        "name",
        "description",
        "location",
        "date_start",
        "date_end",
        "status",
        "type",
        "reminder_time",
        "parent_type",
        "parent_id",
        "deleted",
        "date_modified"
    };

    String queryString = null;
    if (syncAllUsers)
        queryString = "";
    else
    {
        queryString = "meetings.assigned_user_id = 'seed_sarah_id' and meetings.deleted = '0'"; 
        //queryString = "meetings.id IN ( SELECT meeting_id FROM meetings_users WHERE user_id ='"+mUserId+"'";
    }

    entryList.clear();

    while (mResultCount != 0)
    {
        if (!seamless_login())
            return null;

        JSONArray serverEntryList = getEntryList( 
                 "Meetings", fields, queryString, "date_start", 0);

        //... do sth with data
        }
        totalContactsResults += mResultCount;
    }
    logout();
```

login() returns valid session id, and getUserId() returns right id. The whole code is already working for fetching contacts, and also working for a simple query as stated above.

Thanks in advance

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing, I realized, that whitespaces in the query string are the problem. They lead to an URL containing whitespace. To avoid that some kind of URL encoding has to be done.

I had not success in encoding the whole URL in my httpPost methods (seems not to be necessary). But replacing spaces with '+' in the query string works for me:

```
queryString = "meetings.id+IN+(SELECT+meetings_users.meeting_id+FROM meetings_users+WHERE+meetings_users.user_id='"+mUserId+"')";
```

If anyone has a more elegant method of doing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off using the get_relationships web service call.

```
SugarRest.call('get_relationships', [SugarRest.session, 'Users', SugarRest.user_id, 'meetings', '', ['name'], 0, ''])
```

That should be all you need. In the parameter after 'meetings' you can also pass in an additional filter.